# Sendmail MTA, smarthost not working

Tags: linux, debian, sendmail, email, email-server

I have configured Sendmail to work with a smarthost by adding the following line to the configuration

```
define('SMART_HOST', 'smtp.ISP.TLD')dnl
```

and after that I issued

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

The mail log shows

```
Aug  8 17:51:23 mailserver sendmail[10677]: o78FpM8q010677: from=XXXXXXXX, size=64, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201008081551.o78FpM8q010677@mainframe.domain.tld>, relay=root@localhost
Aug  8 17:51:23 mailserver sm-mta[10678]: o78FpNmK010678: from=<XXXXXXXX@mainframe.domain.tld>, size=360, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201008081551.o78FpM8q010677@mainframe.domain.tld>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=mainframe.domain.tld [127.0.0.1]
Aug  8 17:51:23 mailserver sendmail[10677]: o78FpM8q010677: to=XXXXXXXX@gmail.com, ctladdr=XXXXXXXX (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30064, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (o78FpNmK010678 Message accepted for delivery)
```

So it seems it never passes on to the smarthost.
Oh yes, and I'm using Debian 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it didn't compile correctly, now I just modified the compiled file, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DS in your sendmail.cf file it seems the make is not updating, i think i remember debian does their configuration in a non standard way but just do not remember how.